# adjustable textbox expand up and to right

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3"> <asp:Table runat="server"  ID="tblNotes" Width="100%">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell><br />Notes:</asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell> <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udpNotes" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNotes" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="99%" Rows="7" /><br />                                
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
 </asp:TableCell>
```

The above code shows a multiline textbox that expands and is adjustable and the user to do so in the bottom right corner of the textbox.  Is there a way to make the adjustable button in the textbox in the top right corner instead of the bottom right or flip it?